# how to turn on implicit type conversion in hive above version 2.2.0?

Tags: hive, hiveql

see:https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-14251

For example, I have two table ddl:

```
create table_a (id bigint, grade bigint);
create table_b (id string, name string,age bigint);
```

1.when I want to join these table , I have to write `on table_a.id = cast(table_b.id as bigint)`

2.when I use `union all`, I have to do `cast(table_b.id as bigint)` too

3.when I calculate time, I have to use `cast(date_sub('20200804',1) as bigint)*100` to get zero hour on a certain day

It's not problem for using display conversion to write new tasks, But I have a lot of history sql to change..

I'm looking for a configuration that supports implicit conversion. In addition, I think that high-level things should not cut off old features, which will cause incompatibility.